# Is it allowed to carry the Quran in a shoulder bag?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, respect

I saw the etiquette of respecting the *Holy Quran* on a [site](http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/jewels-of-quran.php) that

- one shouldn't not put their back towards the Quran or
- extend their legs towards the Quran or
- sit in a high place when the Quran is beneath.

I want to carry the Holy Quran with me when I'm on a long trip. Is it permitted in Islam to carry it in my double-sided shoulder bag?

Please support your answer with references from hadiths or from the Quran.

Comment: Reference of Hadiths or Quran is required to make something Haram, not Halal. e.g. If I say milk is Haram then I have to provide reference from Quran and/or Hadith. So if someone will give you that it is Haram to carry Quran in shoulder bag then s/he has to give reference from Quran and/or hadith. Otherwise not i.e. if I tell you (for the sake of argument) that it is totally legal then I don't have to give you reference from Quran/Hadith.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok for you to carry the Mushaf in your bag, there is no proof (to my knowledge) that would forbid this. You can try to make sure that the bag you put it in is clean, meaning there is no najis in it.

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 3):

That (this) is indeed a noble Qur'an 
In a Book kept hidden 
Which none toucheth save the purified, 
A Revelation from the Lord of the Worlds.
(A-Quran)

"By no means! Indeed it is a message of Instruction
Therefore, whoever wills, should remember
On leaves held in honour
Exalted, purified
In the hands of scribes
Noble and pious"
Sura' 80: 11-16

In the light of above sura 80 v#:11-16, The Quran can be placed at any place except where there is Nijasat(impurity) or Thing which is made of unclean things made haram to us. Remember one thing, First the Holy scripts of Quran was present on leaves held in honour now ask about bag. So in my views You can place Quran in your bag but make sure it is clean and not made up of the material made haram to Muslims. Allah knows the best

Comment: +1 Far better and correct answer in the light of verse and historical background.